# Oracle PL/SQL CONNECT BY PRIOR ... START WITH statement in SQL Server

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2014, database-migration

```
    select distinct sel.empty_tu_loc_id, sel.loc_id from 
(
    SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT LOC_ID_PARENT AS empty_tu_loc_id, LN.LOC_ID AS loc_id
    FROM LN_LOC_LOC LN
    CONNECT BY PRIOR LOC_ID = LOC_ID_PARENT and link_type = 'PARENT'
    START WITH LOC_ID_PARENT IN (SELECT e.loc_id FROM empty_tu_loc e inner join grp g on g.loc_id= e.loc_id)
) sel
left outer join empty_tu_loc e1 on e1.loc_id=sel.loc_id
where e1.loc_id is null
union all 
SELECT distinct loc_id, loc_id FROM empty_tu_loc
);
```

I confused:
How to migrate this code to ms sql-sever 2014?

Comment: Your question undoubtedly has been asked before in e general sense of "sql server equivalent of oracle connect by prior" - have a Google around, try some things hen make a question with what you tried if you can't get it working. This way your question won't be downvoted so harshly- typically SO users try to help out when it's clear the original asker has done some efforts, not just dumped on them as if there a free code writing service

Answer (score 0):

You can try recursive common table expressions (CTE).
Have a look here 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bdab27a0-c1f5-477f-99ed-77f73cf0ea56/how-do-i-replace-the-usage-of-connect-by-prior-in-sql-server-2008r2-?forum=transactsql

Comment: As a side note, when referring to sites that aren't Stack Overflow, like you did with MsDN here, we should try to include relevant data from that site here.. that way if MSDN ever shut down this answer still valid and doesn't have a broken link. Or you can link to another stack overflow post without needing to copy the contents of it to here. THere will surely be a question about this connect by prior equivalent  on SO